# Window not working after reopen

Tags: angularjs, http, window

I am working on a project in which I have to open a second window from the first one. The problem I encounter is that once I reopen the second window (after closing it) I get an JS error and no functions from the window work anymore (DOM Exception)

Here is the code for opening the window:

```
$scope.openPopupWindow = function() {
 popupWindow = window.open('/show');
}
```

Here is the error it gives the second time I open the window:

```
message: "Failed to execute 'setTimeout' on 'Window': No script context is available in which to execute the script."
name: "InvalidAccessError"
```

Here is the code that throws the error:

```
Transaction.get({ transactionId: id }, function(transaction) {
  angular.extend($scope.transactions[$scope.currentTransaction], transaction);
});
```

This uses angular's $resource to make an $http request.

If you need more information please ask, I have tried to solve this problem for some time now and I cannot seem to find a solution. Thanks for your help!

Update: The problem seems to come from angular's $http. If I remove it and use ajax from jQuery or ajaxHttp from raw javascript I encounter not problem. Any solution to this? besides replacing $http with jQuery/pure js.

Comment: Did you find out the reason for the $http's behavior?